# Why is Postman making copies of itself?

Tags: postman

I was looking to see what was taking the most space in my Linux and it seems that [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) is taking up more than 10GB. When I look to see inside the Postman folder there were multiple copies of Postman. Each folder named `Postman-*` contain similar file structures.

**What are these folders and is it safe to delete them?**

```
$> ls /opt/Postman
app                           Postman-1532596129667.tar.gz
Postman                       Postman-1533027652893
Postman-1530100073446         Postman-1533027652893.tar.gz
Postman-1530100073446.tar.gz  Postman-1533109201340
Postman-1530502467861         Postman-1533109201340.tar.gz
Postman-1530502467861.tar.gz  Postman-1533211632278
Postman-1530548958266         Postman-1533211632278.tar.gz
Postman-1530548958266.tar.gz  Postman-1533298799711
Postman-1530614209651         Postman-1533298799711.tar.gz
Postman-1530614209651.tar.gz  Postman-1543299375259
Postman-1530639201747         Postman-1543299375259.tar.gz
Postman-1530639201747.tar.gz  Postman-1543356618240
Postman-1530695631727         Postman-1543356618240.tar.gz
Postman-1530695631727.tar.gz  Postman-1543456897196
Postman-1530760815915         Postman-1543456897196.tar.gz
Postman-1530760815915.tar.gz  Postman-1545899867039
Postman-1530868533963         Postman-1545899867039.tar.gz
Postman-1530868533963.tar.gz  Postman-1545986063838
Postman-1530966538042         Postman-1545986063838.tar.gz
Postman-1530966538042.tar.gz  Postman-1550831701515
Postman-1531113169936         Postman-1550831701515.tar.gz
Postman-1531113169936.tar.gz  Postman-1551281956647
Postman-1531194016556         Postman-1551281956647.tar.gz
Postman-1531194016556.tar.gz  Postman-1551502470093.tar.gz
Postman-1531244697472         Postman-1551829875874
Postman-1531244697472.tar.gz  Postman-1551829875874.tar.gz
Postman-1531310725938         Postman-1551871761724
Postman-1531310725938.tar.gz  Postman-1551871761724.tar.gz
Postman-1531404789953         Postman-1552390222353
Postman-1531404789953.tar.gz  Postman-1552390222353.tar.gz
Postman-1531561796549         Postman-1552465900709.tar.gz
Postman-1531561796549.tar.gz  Postman-1552468361004
Postman-1531719815077         Postman-1552468361004.tar.gz
Postman-1531719815077.tar.gz  Postman-1552726694895
Postman-1531814122704         Postman-1552726694895.tar.gz
Postman-1531814122704.tar.gz  Postman-1552886691974
Postman-1531888113788         Postman-1552886691974.tar.gz
Postman-1531888113788.tar.gz  Postman-1552922993260
Postman-1531987737860         Postman-1552922993260.tar.gz
Postman-1531987737860.tar.gz  Postman-1553578717870
Postman-1532001595115         Postman-1553578717870.tar.gz
Postman-1532001595115.tar.gz  Postman-1554298784465
Postman-1532513970668         Postman-1554298784465.tar.gz
Postman-1532513970668.tar.gz  Postman-1554698548506
Postman-1532590401622         Postman-1554698548506.tar.gz
Postman-1532590401622.tar.gz  Postman.png
Postman-1532596129667
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was reported in v6.1.3 [here](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/5034) and [here](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/6196) which was fixed in 7.0.7.

Also, to answer your second question, yes they are safe to be deleted. You can do `rm -rf Postman-*` to delete them.